# Is there a R function to use a code for a file list

Tags: r

I want to use the following code on a file list, so i don't have to write it for every data frame.
The data frames have 2 columns (x,y) with numeric data.
I hope someone has an easy solution.

```
    file_list <- list(Track1.txt,Track2.txt,
                  Track4.txt,Track5.txt)
##center
a = 250
b = 250

A1 <- 
if_else (Track1.txt$V2 > 0, 
         round(((acos((Track1.txt$V1-a)/sqrt(((Track1.txt$V1-a)^2)+((Track1.txt$V2-b)^2))))
                              *(180/pi)),
                             digits = 0), 
         round(((-acos((Track1.txt$V1-a)/sqrt(((Track1.txt$V1-a)^2)+((Track1.txt$V2-b)^2))))
                 *(180/pi))+360,
                digits = 0)
         )
A1 <- if_else (A1 > 270,A1-270,A1+90)
A1 <- as.data.frame(A1)
```

Comment: Take a look at `lapply`, which you'd use like `lapply(your_file_list, function(i) { [your code here as a function] })`.

Comment: I tried it, but i get an error. Track <- lapply(file_list, function(T1) {
  if_else (T1[2] > 0, 
           round(((acos((T1[1]-a)/sqrt(((T1[1]-a)^2)+((T1[2]-b)^2))))
                  *(180/pi)),
                 digits = 0), 
           round(((-acos((T1[1]-a)/sqrt(((T1[1]-a)^2)+((T1[2]-b)^2))))
                  *(180/pi))+360,
                 digits = 0)
  )
})

Comment: I didn't mean that code to be taken verbatim. Just suggesting a starting point.